# Retrofit 2: Parsing data structure in list of list without Java 8

Tags: java, android, retrofit

We are working on a Android application and I have a task of parsing a json data structure which looks like this:

`[ [{pojo}], [{pojo}], [{pojo}], [{pojo}], ....]`

As you can see, the pojo is what I need but it is buried several layers deep (list -> list -> 0th position).

We have a `minSDKVersion` of 16, and to use the `steam` API, we have to bump it API 24 which we don't want, and I didn't want to import any external dependencies just to solve this one problem

When I first looked at this, I don't see any reason why you want to structure your data like this and don't see any real value, but since changing this in the backend requires a lot of time, I will just have to make this work.

Truth be told, I have no clue where to even start because since there are no fields, I can't create a `pojo` to capture the list, please help, thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the interface method for retrofit:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("api/driverApi/driverSearchLoad.php")
Call<List<JobRequestSchema>> fetchJobRequestsHistory(
        @Field("driverEmail") String driverEmail);
```

This will get called every time user requests it and reason I am having trouble is the response from the server is in the form of:

`[ [{POJO}], [{POJO}], [{POJO}], [{POJO}], .... ]`

What should I do to extract out the POJO?

Here is my POJO class:

```
public class JobRequestSchema {

    public JobRequestSchema(String companyName, String loadTitle, String pickUpAddress, String dropOffAddress, String details, String loadDescription, String amountOffered, String companyEmail, String timeStamp, String requestId) {
        this.companyName = companyName;
        this.loadTitle = loadTitle;
        this.pickUpAddress = pickUpAddress;
        this.dropOffAddress = dropOffAddress;
        this.details = details;
        this.loadDescription = loadDescription;
        this.amountOffered = amountOffered;
        this.companyEmail = companyEmail;
        this.timeStamp = timeStamp;
        this.requestId = requestId;
    }

    @SerializedName("id") private String id;
    @SerializedName("request_id") private String requestId;
    @SerializedName("business_name") private String companyName;
    @SerializedName("business_email") private String companyEmail;
    @SerializedName("title") private String loadTitle;
    @SerializedName("details") private String details;
    @SerializedName("load_description") private String loadDescription;
    @SerializedName("amount_offered") private String amountOffered;
    @SerializedName("pickup_address") private String pickUpAddress;
    @SerializedName("dropoff_address") private String dropOffAddress;
    @SerializedName("timestamp") private String timeStamp;

    // getters and setters....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try your network call in Postman for example, get the response, and copy/paste response to http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/. Download the result and use it in your project. Sorry that i couldn't help more without seeing some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Install the plugin in IntelliJ / Android Studio by opening Preferences -> Plugins -> Search for "Json2Pojo".
Right-click on the target package, select New -> "Generate POJOs from JSON".
Enter the root class name and enter your source JSON text.
```

My suggestion is do not upload you data to some unknown remote web site.

And follow the link for parsing,
https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html

Comment: Updated sample link for parsing.